# Determining whether a line is inside an itemize or enumerate environment

Tags: environments, enumerate, itemize

I would like to be able to tell whether a line is inside `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}` or `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}`.  My need for this stems from incrementing a counter for the outermost \begin.

Comment: Why don't you just increment the counter only when you are starting an outermost `itemize` or `enumerate`? Could you please post a minimal example to better explain your question? It is rather hard to guess what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newif\ifinside
\setlist[itemize,enumerate,1]{before*={\ifinside\relax\else\stepcounter{mycounter}\insidetrue\fi},after*={\insidefalse}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item three
    \item four
    \begin{itemize}
      \item thing
      \item thing
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\themycounter
\begin{itemize}
  \item thing
  \item thing
  \item thing
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \item two
    \begin{itemize}
      \item thing
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item three
        \item four
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\themycounter
\end{document}
```

[image: counting outer lists]

Comment: Excellent.  I am puzzled at what is setting `inside` to `true` though.

Comment: `before*={\ifinside\relax\else\stepcounter{mycounter}\insidetrue\fi}`. If it is not already true, it steps the counter and makes it true as well. At the end of the environment, it sets it false.